# Copy large file between azure storage account gen 2 using c# code

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

We have files store in azure storage account gen 2

We are using api approach to create,delete and read the files [ as mention here
[Read File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/read) ]

We are trying to copying the file from one storage account to another using api approach. Can someone suggest fast approach to achieve it ?

Note:

- I am looking for code approach in c# without AzCopy
- In Gen 1, Data Movement Library is there but I am looking for Gen 2

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

you could use AzCopy to transfer data. You could copy data between a file system and a storage account, or between storage accounts with AzCopy.

About the details how to use AzCopy you could refer to this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json). In this doc , there are download link and the tutorials.

**Update:**
About transfer files between file shares you could refer to this code:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount1.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare1/ /Dest:https://myaccount2.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare2/ /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /S
```

Other about Copy files in File Storage you could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json#copy-files-in-file-storage).

If you still have other questions, please let me know. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but looking for c# code, I added c# tag initially thought it will be clear by that, updated question

Comment: I will not mark it as answer but since you spend time on my question, I will give upvote :)

Comment: Its Gen 1 code and for Gen 2 the library is not release yet thats the reason I am using api call

Comment: @user2463514 Due to it's a preview version looks like there is not relevant SDK for now. And I found a new doc you could move data with Data Factory.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's very hard to find the working solution because the official documentation is outdated and there is a lack of any up-to-date examples there.

**Outdated way**

An outdated example of working with blob containers could be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows

That example uses `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet package that was renamed to `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.*` and split to separate packages.

**Up-to-date solution**

*I'm currently working on the deployment of the static SPA to Azure Blob storage. It has a very nice feature "Static website" that serves the files.*

There is a working example that could be used to copy all contents from one blob container to another. Please consider it as a hint (not production ready).

All you need is to:

- Have an existing blob container.
- Install `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement` NuGet package.
- Provide a proper connection string.

Here is the code:

```
// I left fully qualified names of the types to make example clear.

var connectionString = "Connection string from `Azure Portal > Storage account > Access Keys`";

var sourceContainerName = "<source>";
var destinationContainerName = "<destination>";

var storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var sourceContainer = client.GetContainerReference(sourceContainerName);

var destinationContainer = client.GetContainerReference(destinationContainerName);
// Create destination container if needed
await destinationContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var sourceBlobDir = sourceContainer.GetDirectoryReference(""); // Root directory
var destBlobDir = destinationContainer.GetDirectoryReference("");

// Use UploadOptions to set ContentType of destination CloudBlob
var options = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.CopyDirectoryOptions
{
    Recursive = true,
};

var context = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.DirectoryTransferContext();

// Perform the copy
var transferStatus = await Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager
    .CopyDirectoryAsync(sourceBlobDir, destBlobDir, true, options, context);
```

Comment: Is this solution applicable for ADLS Gen2 ?

Comment: It's applicable for Azure Storage account v2.
And, actually, `DataMovement` package is the core for `AzCopy`. So, I guess that things that could be done with `AzCopy`, they could be done with `DataMovement` as well.

Comment: Do you have any sample for TransferManager.CopyAsync Method (CloudBlob, CloudFile, Boolean) ?